# Rabbi Yonasan Eibshetz on the Messiah and Redemption

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books

The [BIN](http://www.breakingisraelnews.com/47934/prophecy-fulfilled-sept-4-2015-opinion/#cZMjYqt2TxvUS4cG.97) says the following:

"Rabbi Yonasan Eibshetz in his book ***Ya’aros Dvash*** states, *'At a certain moment the time will come when the Messiah should have already arrived but the redemption has not yet come. The Messiah will ask how it could be that the time for redemption has arrived and he still undergoes sufferings? The response that he will receive is that he must wait for nine months. Why? In order to wait for the fall of Persia (Iran) at the hands of Edom (the Christian West), and then the final redemption will come!"*

Does anyone know where Rabbi Yonasan Eibshetz says this in ***Ya’aros Dvash***?

Comment: Is this question on topic? It kind of just seems like you're asking us to do the work of looking for this for you.

Comment: @Daniel ...and?

Comment: @High and similar questions on other SE sites like stack overflow are considered off-topic so I'm trying to determine whether we have a similar policy.

Comment: @Hugh ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @Daniel I don't think asking for the location of a quote from a specific sefer should be considered off topic; but that's just my opinion, I haven't thorougly familiarized myself with the guidelines here

Comment: @Hugh Seems thoroughly on topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

יערות דבש חלק ב, דרוש י״ג,  לז׳ אדר, ד״ה ואמרינן בגמרא (מגלה יב) כה אמר ה׳

Here's a link to the page:

[http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32683&hilite=b8eee4df-a3a0-4c9b-af99-91d992d48e4c&st=הפרסיים&pgnum=353](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32683&hilite=b8eee4df-a3a0-4c9b-af99-91d992d48e4c&st=%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D&pgnum=353)

Comment: +1 perhaps add the relevant text?

Comment: @mevaqesh Per your request.

Comment: What for the people who doesn't speak hebrew ? :P

Comment: @mil to my knowledge there isn't an English translation of Sefer Yaarot D'vash. But I can appreciate your frustration. As a possible, although tedious, work-around you might consider working through Google Translate and typing the text manually. I don't think it would do well with the Aramaic sections but it would get you in the neighborhood.